# how do I return the correct price and amount to the product using sort?

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to sort 3 lists. ive made sure that the amounts and prices correspond to the products but now i need to sort them. how do i make sure that the amount and price gets sorted to the right product?

```
item_list = ["creatine", "ashwagandha", "whey", "bcaa", "multivitamins", "omega-3", "magnesium", "zinc"]
quantity_items = [12, 4, 7, 16, 15, 19, 10, 8]
prices = [1999, 1500, 2500, 2100, 1399, 1200, 1299, 1199, 1000]
menu_list = ["1: Buy another item", "2: View shopping cart", "3: Delete item from cart", "4: Check-out"]

# lists with chosen items
cart = []
amounts = []
total_price = []
```

this is how far ive come (the code is longen but this is probably the only important part to see).

Comment: Do you have to have 4 separate lists? Why not use a list of dictionaries, and sort that list on a key?

Comment: You could also use zip function to form a tuple containing each item, qty, & price